# OpenERP 7 disable manual entry on date control

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I understand that OpenERP 7 is outdated and no longer has any support

but as this question is important I need to ask it here
I am new to OpenERP 7 and we hired a freelancer to do some work for us

we needed the date of the entry to be limited to today, yesterday and the day before it

The freelancer did limit it though the selection but if the user types the date manually, it will still accept the entry

I mentioned to him this loophole and how it would make problems for us, but he claims that he would need to change a js file and it would be hard to accomplish

I took his word but my manager wants to confirm that I have not been tricked hence, this question

So, how possible is it to accomplish the mentioned above?

Comment: I don't think limiting the date could only be achieved by js changes. Just use Odoo's onchange mechanism, throw warnings and set dates in this limit.

Comment: he claims that it wont work

Comment: We're speaking of creating/updating a record of a model with a date field, which should be limited? Using the onchange mechanism should be no problem for that requirement.

Comment: An other solution is overriding the create and write function and make them check the values entered. If they are not as expected you could raise an error. (this only works as a check after the user already manually entered the value) 
Combine it with an onchange and you tackle both (what the user sees and the actual write/create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is absolutely possible.
You can use onchange or _constraints for this :

If you want to check a condition  on the fly you can use **onchange** or if you want to check a condition at the time of save you can use **_constraints** .

Examples:

```
    def _check_duration(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for obj_ac in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if obj_ac.date_stop < obj_ac.date_start:
            return False
    return True

_constraints = [
    (_check_duration, _('Error! The duration of the academic year is invalid.'), ['date_stop']),
]

    def onchange_date(self, cr, uid, ids, date, context=None):
    if date:
        if Condition Here:
            warning = "Your text"
            return {'value':{'date': None}, 'warning':warning}
        else:
            return {}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not skilled in OpenERP programming, but if that code would achieve my needs then good enough
this question's purpose was to confirm that it is possible